# Can't able to apply css file in html5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have been creating a simple webpage using HTML5,CSS and jQuery.

I am working on this webpage for long days.. and when I opened this webpage yesterday as usual, suddenly it shows this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MobDe.jpg

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Design Website</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <script src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="demo-one">

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div id = "wrap">

      <!-- Header --> 

      <header>
      <div id="address">255 Nandanam,  linefocus CT 06810 | + 044 - 4386 1111 | <a href="mailto:info@linefocus.com" class="white">info@linefocus.com</a></div>
        <div id="logo"><img class="header-image" src="img/Untitled-1.png" alt="Church Of Our Lady Of Health - Pattabiram Military Siding" />
        <h5 class="caption">Church Of Our Lady Of Health - Pattabiram Military Siding</h5>

        </div>

          <!-- Search box --> 
        <form>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
          <!-- End Search box --> 


          <!-- Navigation --> 
        <nav id="menu-wrap">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="/">ABOUT CHURCH</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">PARISH PRIEST</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="">MASS TIMINGS</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">CSS</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Item 11</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 12</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 13</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 14</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Graphic design</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Item 21</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 22</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 23</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 24</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Development tools</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Item 31</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 32</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 33</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 34</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Web design</a>               
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Item 41</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 42</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 43</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Item 44</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">PRAYERS</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">Work 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 11</a>      
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 111</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 112</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 113</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 12</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 121</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 122</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 123</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 13</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 131</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 132</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 133</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Work 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 21</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 211</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 212</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 213</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 22</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 221</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 222</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 223</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 23</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 231</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 232</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 233</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Work 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 31</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 311</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 312</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 313</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 32</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 321</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 322</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 323</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Work 33</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">Work 331</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 332</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Work 333</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">NEW CHURCH</a>
          <ul>
                      <li><a href="">COMMITTEE MEMBERS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">DONATIONS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
          <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- End Navigation -->

      </header>

        <!-- End Header --> 

      <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> 
      <div id="wowslider-container1">
        <div class="ws_images">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="data1/images/church.jpg" alt="BentonCountySO" title="BentonCountySO" id="wows1_0"/></li>
            <li><a href="http://wowslider.com/vf"><img src="data1/images/intro7.jpg" alt="full screen slider" title="ColumbiaFD" id="wows1_1"/></a></li>
            <li><img src="data1/images/intro2.jpg" alt="FriendsSD" title="FriendsSD" id="wows1_2"/></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_bullets">
          <div>
            <a href="#" title="BentonCountySO"><img src="data1/tooltips/church.jpg" alt="BentonCountySO"/>1</a>
            <a href="#" title="ColumbiaFD"><img src="data1/tooltips/intro7.jpg" alt="ColumbiaFD"/>2</a>
            <a href="#" title="FriendsSD"><img src="data1/tooltips/intro2.jpg" alt="FriendsSD"/>3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
      </div>
        <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section --> 

<!--main-->
<main class="clearfix"> 
<aside class="sidebar">
<div class="inside">
<section id="content">

        <!--Start Login Form --> 

        <form action="">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

            </div>
            <p class="member">Not a member?&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Signup</a></p>
        </form>

        <!-- End form -->

    </section>

    </div>
            <!-- Youtube palyer-1 -->

    <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="315" height="184" poster="http://s24.postimg.org/p6qvm6c11/2lv1kc4.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
    </section>
    </div>
                <!-- Youtube palyer-2 -->

    <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="315" height="184" poster="http://s9.postimg.org/7od5o9t27/cc_names_fb.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>
    </section>
    </div>
                    <!-- Facebook Page -->

        <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/JesusDaily" data-width="315px" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>   </section>
    </div>

    <!-- News Feed -->
        <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">
    <div class="holder">
    <h2><u>News</u></h2>
  <ul id="ticker01">
                            <li><span>10/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints</a></li>
                            <li><span>10/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Jesus replied, “They do not need to go away. You give them something to eat.</a></li>
                            <li><span>10/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Polygamy essays provide information about early LDS Church</a></li>
                            <li><span>08/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Young LDS mother claims Ironman title</a></li>
                            <li><span>08/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">LDS World: We must teach our children to pray</a></li>
                            <li><span>05/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Problematically, however, the Javascript code</a></li>
                            <li><span>04/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Women in the Bible focus of art display</a></li>
                            <li><span>04/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">How faith is making modest fashion trendy</a></li>
                            <li><span>04/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">LDS Charitites partners to help women in Iraq</a></li>
                            <li><span>03/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Seven tech products to strengthen youth</a></li>
                            <li><span>03/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">LDS husband and father is also a firefighter and wakeboard world champion</a></li>
                            <li><span>01/10/2014</span>&nbsp;<a href="#">Elder David Rodger Stone passes away</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>

   </section>
   </div>

    </aside>
<!--main content-->
<div class="main_content" class="content">
<h1>About Church</h1>
<h4>A Brief History:</h4>
<p>In order to cater to the pastoral needs of the military personnel and the railway employees at Pattabiram military siding, a temporary shed functioned as a Church, since 1946. The local Catholics, especially Shri P John raised enough funds to construct a small Chapel in the place of the shed. This was blessed by His Excellency Dr Francis Carvalho, Auxiliary Bishop of Madras-Mylapore on 22nd April 1955. Right from 1946, the feast of Our Lady of Velankanni is celebrated in this parish. In 1973 it was erected as a separate parish. The first Parish Priest was Fr Philip Manathara who built the present Church.</p>
<p>Church's type theory is a formal logical language which includes first-order logic, but is more expressive in a practical sense. It is used, with some modifications and enhancements, in most modern applications of type theory. It is particularly well suited to the formalization of mathematics and other disciplines and to specifying and verifying hardware and software. It also plays an important role in the study of the formal semantics of natural language.</p>
<h2>Domestic Doners</h2>
<p>Type theories are also called higher-order logics, since they allow quantification not only over individual variables (as in first-order logic), but also over function, predicate, and even higher order variables. Type theories characteristically assign types to entities, distinguishing, for example, between numbers, set of numbers, functions from numbers to sets of numbers, and sets of such functions. As illustrated in Section 1.2.2 below, these distinctions allow one to discuss the conceptually rich world of sets and functions without encountering the paradoxes of naive set theory.</p>
<h4>Catholic Population :</h4><p>2,8000</p>
<h4>Sunday Mass – Timings & Language :</h4>
<ul>
<li>6.30 am, 8.00 am (Pattabiram)</li>
<li>8.00 am (Muthapudupet) – Tamil</li>
</ul>
<h4>Sub-stations with Chapel</h4>
<ul><li>01 Sacred Jesus Chapel, Sastri Nagar, 1 km</li>
<li>02 Infant Jesus Chapel, Mosque Street, Muthapudupet, 4 kms</li>
</ul>
<h4>Participatory Structures</h4>
<ul>
<li>01 Parish Pastoral Council</li>
<li>02 Parish Finance Committee</li>
<li>03 Anbiyams</li>
</ul>
<h4>Associations</h4>
<ul>
<li>01 Altar Servers</li>
<li>02 Charismatic Renewal</li>
<li>03 Legion of Mary</li>
<li>04 St Vincent de Paul</li>
<li>05 Youth Group – Tamil</li>
<li>06 Madhar Sangam</li>
</ul>
<h4>Religious</h4>
<p> 01 Franciscan Sisters of St Elizabeth (FSE) Tel 044 – 65 68 16 40</p>
<h4>Institution under the Religious</h4>
<p> 01 Home for Poor Gilrs Tel 044 – 65 68 16 40</p>
<p>In pretium magna nec purus elementum malesuada. Mauris pulvinar mauris tempor tellus laoreet, non sollicitudin dolor porttitor. Duis rutrum pretium dignissim. Integer non leo id orci placerat sollicitudin vel quis velit. Praesent sit amet mi eget ante pellentesque tincidunt ac quis turpis. Sed vitae fringilla nisi, sit amet tincidunt sem. Praesent luctus odio ac laoreet commodo. Vivamus a consequat magna. Suspendisse potenti. Nam cursus molestie lobortis.</p>
<h3>About Exisiting Church </h3>
<p>Type theories are also called higher-order logics, since they allow quantification not only over individual variables (as in first-order logic), but also over function, predicate, and even higher order variables. Type theories characteristically assign types to entities, distinguishing, for example, between numbers, set of numbers, functions from numbers to sets of numbers, and sets of such functions. As illustrated in Section 1.2.2 below, these distinctions allow one to discuss the conceptually rich world of sets and functions without encountering the paradoxes of naive set theory.</p>
<h3>About Proposed Church</h3>
<p>Church's type theory is a formulation of type theory that was introduced by Alonzo Church in Church 1940. In certain respects, it is simpler and more general than the type theory introduced by Bertrand Russell in Russell 1908 and Whitehead & Russell 1927a. Since properties and relations can be regarded as functions from entities to truth values, the concept of a function is taken as primitive in Church's type theory, and the λ-notation which Church introduced in Church 1932 and Church 1941 is incorporated into the formal language.</p>
<p>Church's type theory is a formulation of type theory that was introduced by Alonzo Church in Church 1940. In certain respects, it is simpler and more general than the type theory introduced by Bertrand Russell in Russell 1908 and Whitehead & Russell 1927a. Since properties and relations can be regarded as functions from entities to truth values, the concept of a function is taken as primitive in Church's type theory, and the λ-notation which Church introduced in Church 1932 and Church 1941 is incorporated into the formal language.</p>

</div>
<!--end main content--> 

</main>
<!--end main--> 
 <!-- #footer -->
    <div id="footer" class="footer page">


        <!-- #footer > #links-home -->
        <div id="links-home" class="links">
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/home/accessibility/">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/home/sitemap/">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/home/search/">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/home/rss/">RSS newsfeed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/home/smallscreen/">Small-screen layout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- #footer > #links-portfolio -->
        <div id="links-portfolio" class="links">
            <h3>Portfolio</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/portfolio/cv/">CV</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/portfolio/books/">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/portfolio/articles/">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/portfolio/tools/">Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/portfolio/blogging/">Blogging</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- #footer > #links-resources -->
        <div id="links-resources" class="links">
            <h3>Resources</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/">Scripts</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/games/">Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/reference/">Reference</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/terms/">Terms of use</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- #footer > #links-pesonal -->
        <div id="links-personal" class="links">
            <h3>Personal</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/personal/music/">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/personal/cooking/">Cooking</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.brothercake.com/site/personal/brothercake/">Brothercake.com</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="links-contact" class="links">
            <h3>Get in touch</h3>
            <p>
                If you're looking for a quote I'll be happy to discuss your needs,  
                over the phone, skype or IM, or whatever you prefer. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- *** / UNFINISHED *** -->
<address itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <span class="copyright">Copyright © 2014</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="name" itemprop="legalName"> Church Of Our Lady Of Health.</span>


    </address>

    </div>
    <!-- / #footer -->


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
<!--js--sticky-footer--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>

  <script src="js/index-scroll.js"></script>



  </body>


</html>
```

I'm not able to understand what happened. I checked my code again and again, still can't trace the problem.

Can anyone please help me.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what cheap?.. this is my problem

Comment: Please post your code, it's impossible to solve it without code.

Comment: please check if your CSS file is loaded at all. you can check the same in Chrome Developer Tool (Ctrl+Shift+I) and check under Resources tab. your file should be listed under Frames-->Stylesheets

Comment: hope your browser problem try yo run it in another browser.

Comment: Try turn off your browser extension "screencapture" or something similar to it. Or open your file in Incognito mode (CTRL+SHIFT+N)

Comment: sorry @all.. it shows like this http://imgur.com/9Z88jci

Comment: @VivekVikranth: i tried another browser. still stays same.

Comment: @deepika - Looks like your CSS code has gone rogue on you! :p

Comment: @deepika could you please add your image as an inline..? i dont have any access to see url you provided.

Comment: I removed screen capture and still stays same @Anarion

Comment: @chipChocolare.py Lol.

Comment: @deepika check out your css path and see if the css file is in the right directory path. if it is, check out again your css declaration on your html. If nothing else, it is highly possible to miss some '/' or '..'

Comment: see this link http://imgur.com/9Z88jci  @VivekVikranth

Comment: better paste your HTML file here in your question :-)

Comment: @all, please see my posted code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
```

There should be no spaces between attr and its value:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

Comment: This is not answer.. and still i didn't get.

Comment: Is there anybody to help?